# How to increase phpmyadmin upload filesize limit in wampserver?

Tags: wamp

Showing error Request entity too large! The POST method does not allow the data transmitted, or the data volume exceeds the capacity limit in wamp server

Comment: Did you actually try to research your question before posting it? There are already a lot of identical questions with the same problem on here - [ask]

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually that time I searched  but not found correct answer. But now I got once again thankyou so much

Comment: You did not attach any actual code or attempts to your question. How would we know what you've already tried and what's not working?  The question is even tagged poorly